# CultureTypes in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi I want to access the CultureTypes in Windows Phone. In Silverlight/WPF i can use like this,

```
CultureInfo[] specificCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
```

But In Windows  Phone it showing an error as "**UnKnownEntity**" in **CultureTypes**

Also I want to get the Id of the CurrentCulture. In Silverlight/WPF, i can use like

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID
```

But in Windows Phone it showing an error as "**NotFound**" in **LCID**

Could you please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Silverlight/WPF i can use like this

You can in WPF, but not in Silverlight. Look at the [Silverlight version of the documentation for `CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx54z3k7%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - there's no `GetCultures` method. I don't see any way of getting all cultures - just the current culture, current UI culture, and invariant culture. (You can create your own instances by calling the constructor, of course.)

EDIT: You've run into exactly the same problem when trying to get the LCID. You can't just assume everthing from the desktop framework will be available in Silverlight. You need to look at the Silverlight-specific documentation to see what's available (and then check that it's available on Windows Phone 7, too).

Comment: yes yes, i used in WPF i thought it will be same silvelight also. Thanks.

Comment: could you please give any sample for this

Comment: @Ponmalar: For what exactly? I've said I don't know a way of getting all the cultures...

Comment: I am creating CultureInfoType converter. If i'm passing string then it should match with the culture types and return the Culture if it matched.

Comment: @Ponmalar: What do you mean by "match" and "the culture types"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value){
            string strValue = value.ToString();
            CultureInfo converted = culture;
            CultureInfo[] specificCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

            for (int i = 0, cnt = specificCultures.Length; i < cnt; i++){ CultureInfo current = specificCultures[i]; if (current.EnglishName == strValue || current.Name == strValue) {converted = current; break;} - like that i want to add in WP7.
            }

            return converted;
        }

Comment: @Ponmalar: Well as I've said, I'm not sure there *is* a way of getting all the cultures in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You could use T4 generator to generate missing information. I have done this for similiar problem and works great.